# rarfile python чтение

Tags: python, python-3.x, rar

Объясните пожалуйста, почему rarfile не читается как rarfile? Все файлы нормально, а именно этот - так. Он даже показывается, что он с расширением `rar`:

```
edgeDetect.rar
edgeDetect
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Новая папка (2)\Skript.py", line 140, in <module>
    archive= rarfile.RarFile(file,'r')
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rarfile.py", line 685, in __init__
    self._parse()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rarfile.py", line 877, in _parse
    raise BadRarFile("Not a RAR file")
rarfile.BadRarFile: Not a RAR file
```

Comment: Файл-то точно rar или у него просто расширение такое?

Comment: точно rar, несколько раз проверял